# ES6 map array of objects to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, array.prototype.map

There is an array of objects

```
const data = [{
    "name": "08/20/2018",
    "id": "name_1"
}, {
    "name": "12/23/2018",
    "id": "name_2"
}]
```

and I would like to map this array of objects in order to get just array

```
["Date 1","08/20/2018","Date 2","12/23/2018"]
```

I'm trying using `.map()`

```
data.map((d, i) => 
 `${'Date ' + i}`
  d.name
)];
```

but cannot map name with the first (d) parameter.

Comment: ```data.flatMap( (x,i) => [`Date ${i+1}`, x.name])```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the input items and output array items aren't one-to-one, you won't be able to use `.map`. Use `reduce` instead:

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "08/20/2018",
    "id": "name_1"
}, {
    "name": "12/23/2018",
    "id": "name_2"
}];

const output = data.reduce((a, { name }, i) => {
  a.push('Date ' + (i + 1), name);
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```

Or `.flatMap`:

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "08/20/2018",
    "id": "name_1"
}, {
    "name": "12/23/2018",
    "id": "name_2"
}];

const output = data.flatMap(({ name }, i) => (['Date ' + (i + 1), name]));
console.log(output);
```

(note that since arrays are zero-indexed, you'll have to use `i + 1`, not `i`, if you want the first item in the output array to start at 1 instead of 0)

Comment: Yes It seems reduce way is optimized.

Answer (score 1):

Try to combine `map` and `flatmap` methods in order to achieve desired result:

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "08/20/2018",
    "id": "name_1"
}, {
    "name": "12/23/2018",
    "id": "name_2"
}];


const result = data.map((s, i)=> [`Date ${i}`, s.name]).flatMap(f=> f);
console.log(result)
```

or using `flat` method:

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "08/20/2018",
    "id": "name_1"
}, {
    "name": "12/23/2018",
    "id": "name_2"
}];


const result = data.map((s, i)=> [`Date ${i}`, s.name]).flat(1);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) since that method produce a new array with the same number of items of the original ones.

However, you can use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) (where supported) to achieve the your desired result:

```
data.flatMap(({name}, i) => [`Date ${i + 1}`, name]);
console.log(data) // [ "Date 1", "08/20/2018", "Date 2", "12/23/2018" ]
```

Basically `flatMap` is like calling `map` and then [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat); therefore if from the callback function we returns an array per item, this array will be flattened before returned.

Regular `map` call would have been produced `[[ "Date 1", "08/20/2018"], ["Date 2", "12/23/2018"]]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

One line answer using ES2019 `Array.flat` :

```js
data.map((item,index)=>([`Date${index+1}`,item.name])).flat();
```

But in my opinion, it is not optimized when there is huge data.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate above answers but if you still prefer to use `.map()` method to accomplish your work, you can do it.

Just with an additional use of `concat()` method with `map()` method. Let's see how.

> I have used `...data,map()` statement where `...` is used for Array destructuring. More information can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring.

```
const data = [
    {
        "name": "08/20/2018",
        "id": "name_1"
    }, 
    {
        "name": "12/23/2018",
        "id": "name_2"
    }
]

output = new Array() // or just []

output = output.concat(...data.map((obj, index) => [`Date ${index + 1}`, obj.name]))

console.log(output)
// [ 'Date 1', '08/20/2018', 'Date 2', '12/23/2018' ]
```

> Screenshot

[image]